tabulator SQL AJAX data source and Nested tree
all
I have a tabulator that is populated from an SQL query via Ajax. I want to make a Nested Tree from this data; the SQL data has a marker on the top-level row and the last entry of the nested data like so (simplified):
ID   Name    children
1    John    [
2    Paul
3    George
4    Ringo   ]
The response from this returns an array of objects:
ID:1,Name:"John", "_children"[
ID:2,Name:"Paul", null
ID:3,Name:"George", null
ID:4,Name:"Ringo", "]"
My tabulator options are:
    ajaxContentType: "json",
    ajaxConfig: "GET",
    ajaxURL: ajaxURL,
    ajaxParams: {
        trust: loginModel.organisationCode,
        type: refType
    },
    ajaxResponse: function (ajaxURL, params, response) {
    },
    dataTree: true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: false,

Is there any way to load this as a Nested Tree?
Using the Ajax response data work but doesn't give nested tables.
